# Extract part of a text with selenium IDE and put it into variable

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

Could somebody tell me which command should I use to extract only the number(694575) from the text using Selenium Ide and to put it into a variable for further usage.
Here is the div with the text:

```
<div class="loginBoxTitle">Edit Exhibition Centre - 694575, Exhibition Center1</div>
```

May be commands like storeText,storeEval should work in this case ,but the part with the pasrsing is a mistery for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solution, tricky 1

```
store  | Edit Exhibition Centre - 694575, Exhibition Center1 | string
store  | 1 | delimiter   
store  | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('- ')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | test
store  | 0 | delimiter1
store  | javascript{storedVars['test'].split(',')[storedVars['delimiter1']]} | output
echo   | ${output}
```

Try this 1, and let me know whether its working for you

Comment: Accept the answer if its working, so that this will help others too :)

Answer (score 0):

I Have an easy answer to this  question. Try this code it will work.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>Edit Exhibition Centre - 694575, Exhibition Center1</td>
    <td>string</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['string'].substring(24)}</td>
    <td>string</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${string}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['string'].substring(0,7)}</td>
    <td>string</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${string}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```